# how to link 2 classes to share the textfield and their properties

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to run a modification of data code for my desktop application in Java Netbeans IDE, but the problem is before some one has access to modify the data I want to make sure that the person is authorized by providing a username and password in another JFrame form. If the username and password is verified then only the modification task will be successful; otherwise user will get an error of authentication unsuccessful. I tried to write the code in my Main form but when I want to write the code in the button_click event of the authentication form is it possible? I tried but its saying u need to declare the variables of that class in this class any help please..??

This is the Login form with which I want to verify the user for modifying the data once user is verified I want to allow him to run the modification part....

```
  private void loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   if(evt.getSource()==login){
       if((tb_uid.getText().equals(""))||(tb_pwd.getText().equals(""))){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please Enter Valid UserName and Password!");

       }else{
            DBUtil util = new DBUtil();
            String user1 = "";
            String pass1 = "";
            try {

                Connection con = util.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM login where username=?");
                ResultSet res;
                String value1 = tb_uid.getText();
                String value2 = tb_pwd.getText();
                stmt.setString(1, "" + (value1));
                res = stmt.executeQuery();
                while (res.next()) {
                    user1 = res.getString("username");
                    pass1 = res.getString("password");
                }
                if (value1.equals(user1) && value2.equals(pass1)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "AUTHENTICATION SUCCESSFUL!");



                     try {
                Connection con = util.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement stmtn = con.prepareStatement("update soil_det set[weight]=?,[note_state]=?,[dm_state]=?,[1]=?,[2]=?,[5]=?,[10]=?,[20]=?,[50]=?,[100]=?,[500]=?,[1000]=? FROM [CNV].[dbo].[soil_det] where rm_id=? and box_no =?");


                String rmn = (tf_rm_id.getText() == null || tf_rm_id.getText().equals("")) ? "0" : tf_rm_id.getText();
                String an = (txtRe1.getText().trim() == null || txtRe1.getText().equals("")) ? "0" : txtRe1.getText();
                String bn = (txtRs2.getText().trim() == null || txtRs2.getText().equals("")) ? "0" : txtRs2.getText();
                String cn = (txtRs5.getText().trim() == null || txtRs5.getText().equals("")) ? "0" : txtRs5.getText();
                String dn = (txtRs10.getText().trim() == null || txtRs10.getText().equals("")) ? "0" : txtRs10.getText();
                String en = (txtRs20.getText().trim() == null || txtRs20.getText().equals("")) ? "0" : txtRs20.getText();
                String fn = (txtRs50.getText().trim() == null || txtRs50.getText().equals("")) ? "0" : txtRs50.getText();
                String gn = (txtRs100.getText().trim() == null || txtRs100.getText().equals("")) ? "0" : txtRs100.getText();
                String hn = (txtRs500.getText().trim() == null || txtRs500.getText().equals("")) ? "0" : txtRs500.getText();
                String in = (txtRs1000.getText().trim() == null || txtRs1000.getText().equals("")) ? "0" : txtRs1000.getText();
                String bnn = (txtboxno.getText().trim() == null || txtboxno.getText().equals("")) ? "0" : txtboxno.getText();
                String bwn = (txtboxwgt.getText().trim() == null || txtboxwgt.getText().equals("")) ? "0" : txtboxwgt.getText();
                Object nsn = (cbnotstat.getSelectedItem() == null || cbnotstat.getSelectedItem().equals("")) ? "0" : cbnotstat.getSelectedItem();
                Object dsn = (cbdmnstat.getSelectedItem() == null || cbdmnstat.getSelectedItem().equals("")) ? "0" : cbdmnstat.getSelectedItem();


                stmtn.setString(1, "" + (bwn));
                stmtn.setString(2, "" + nsn);
                stmtn.setString(3, "" + dsn);
                stmtn.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(an));
                stmtn.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(bn));
                stmtn.setInt(6, Integer.parseInt(cn));
                stmtn.setInt(7, Integer.parseInt(dn));
                stmtn.setInt(8, Integer.parseInt(en));
                stmtn.setInt(9, Integer.parseInt(fn));
                stmtn.setInt(10, Integer.parseInt(gn));
                stmtn.setInt(11, Integer.parseInt(hn));
                stmtn.setInt(12, Integer.parseInt(in));
                stmtn.setString(13, "" + (rmn));
                stmtn.setInt(14, Integer.parseInt(bnn));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
            }


                        } 
                else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "AUTHERNTICATION UNSUCCESSFUL", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());

    }
    this.dispose();
    }
   }
}
```

But the main problem is with modification part which is from another form..

Comment: I am sorry Mr Andrew for the inconvenience I'll make sure i make it in a proper manner from now onwards.

Comment: You can create a instance of that class and access that fields. Check their access modifiers that they are available to other class. If that field is static then just share that field or method by `ClassName.variableName`

Comment: If you are trying to access a JTextField from another class you actually have to pass the other class the information from that textfield or the whole original class. To pass the whole class, do this when creating a new instance of the other new JFrame: NewJFrameName newFrame = new NewJFrameName(OriginalClassName.this); You also need accessor methods in the original class. If this is kind of what you need let me know and I'll post answer code below.

Comment: Yes, it is like I want to get the information from the JTextfield from a new Frame to my current Frame and then verify the JTextfields's text. It is actually the user name and password what i need to extract from a new JFrame.

Comment: @sage88 OP is requesting for the answer.

Comment: @smit Thanks for the heads up. Answer posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an SSCCE that you can test out to see if this is what you want to be able to do. I first create your login JFrame where the user is asked to enter their credentials. Then to pass that information to another class I pass the whole instance of the Login class to the new class (OtherClass). I have accessor methods in Login which will be used in OtherClass to retrieve the JTextField information that has been stored in strings. If you don't pass the whole Login class, even if you store the JTextField contents in Strings using getText() that information will not be able to be accessed with the accessor methods.

```
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Login extends JFrame
{
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 250;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 100;

    private JPanel labelPanel;
    private JPanel textPanel;

    private JTextField userName;
    private JTextField userPassword;

    private JButton loginButton;

    private String userNameString;
    private String userPasswordString;

    public Login()
    {
        super("Please Login");
        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        labelPanel = new JPanel();
        labelPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("User Name: ");
        labelPanel.add(userLabel);
        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password: ");
        labelPanel.add(passwordLabel);

        textPanel = new JPanel();
        textPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        add(textPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        userName = new JTextField(30);
        userPassword = new JTextField(30);
        textPanel.add(userName);
        textPanel.add(userPassword);

        loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        FrameListener loginListener = new FrameListener();
        loginButton.addActionListener(loginListener);
        add(loginButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);        
    }

    private class FrameListener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();

            if(actionCommand.equals("Login"))
            {
                if(!(userName.getText().equals("")) && !(userPassword.getText().equals("")))
                {
                    userNameString = userName.getText();
                    userPasswordString = userPassword.getText();

                    //Access your database of credentials here


                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            OtherClass mainProgram = new OtherClass(Login.this);
                            mainProgram.setVisible(true);
                        }
                    });
                    dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                Login loginFrame = new Login();
                loginFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public String getUserName()
    { 
        return userNameString;
    }

    public String getUserPassword()
    {
        return userPasswordString;
    }
}
```

And the class that gets this information needs to have:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class OtherClass extends JFrame
{
    final Login loginClass;

    private String userName;
    private String userPassword;

    public OtherClass(Login e)
    {
        loginClass = e;
        userName = loginClass.getUserName();
        userPassword = loginClass.getUserPassword();

        System.out.println("Your User Name is: " + userName);
        System.out.println("Your Password is: " + userPassword);
    }   
}
```

Comment: I think both the class should be in same package..Isn't it?

Comment: @joey rohan They are currently both in the default package. They will run just fine like this. You can put them in whatever package you like though, but yes they should be in the same package.

Comment: If they are in different package,just import the package :p good example +1

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a few JTextFields to pass (as in your login case) you can also just pass each value as a string to the new JFrame class' constructor. This makes it so that you don't have to use accessor methods. It can also make the parameters for the constructor quite messy if you have a lot of fields to pass.

```
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Login extends JFrame
{
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 250;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 100;

    private JPanel labelPanel;
    private JPanel textPanel;

    private JTextField userName;
    private JTextField userPassword;

    private JButton loginButton;

    private String userNameString;
    private String userPasswordString;

    public Login()
    {
        super("Please Login");
        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        labelPanel = new JPanel();
        labelPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("User Name: ");
        labelPanel.add(userLabel);
        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password: ");
        labelPanel.add(passwordLabel);

        textPanel = new JPanel();
        textPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        add(textPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        userName = new JTextField(30);
        userPassword = new JTextField(30);
        textPanel.add(userName);
        textPanel.add(userPassword);

        loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        FrameListener loginListener = new FrameListener();
        loginButton.addActionListener(loginListener);
        add(loginButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);        
    }

    private class FrameListener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();

            if(actionCommand.equals("Login"))
            {
                if(!(userName.getText().equals("")) && !(userPassword.getText().equals("")))
                {
                    userNameString = userName.getText();
                    userPasswordString = userPassword.getText();

                    //Access your database of credentials here

                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            OtherClass mainProgram = new OtherClass(userNameString, userPasswordString); //Here we pass the String values instead of the whole class
                            mainProgram.setVisible(true);
                        }
                    });
                    dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                Login loginFrame = new Login();
                loginFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    //Note we no longer need accessor methods
}
```

And the OtherClass which now has String parameters in the constructor:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class OtherClass extends JFrame
{
    private String userName;
    private String userPassword;

    public OtherClass(String n, String p)
    {
        userName = n;
        userPassword = p;

        System.out.println("Your User Name is: " + userName);
        System.out.println("Your Password is: " + userPassword);
    }   
}
```

Keep in mind that it is better to pass the string values that have gone through your if-else control structure rather than to pass the string values obtained by using userName.getText(); The checks will still be done, but I think it's a better idea to pass the checked Strings instead.